# Как вернуть функцию JS из контроллера?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

В net framework в контроллере можно было вернуть функцию js.
Столкнулся с тем что в core такой подход не работает.
Пробовал все что выдумывалось и находил в интернете, либо не получалось, либо текст скрипта возвращался.

Форма

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VID)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.W, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">                        
                    @Html.DropDownList("ItemsID", null, String.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "js-source-states" })
                    <input value="Erase" onclick="init();" type="button">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn-default btn2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Контроллер

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult _Edit_object(int id, string ItemsID)
    {
        ...

        db.SaveChanges();     
        
        return ???;
    }
```

В net framework в контроллере можно было вернуть функцию js, страница не перезагружалась и скрипт выполнял необходимые действия на странице.

```
return JavaScript("OnSuccess();");
```

Как похожее реализовать на core?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32659255/6808809

Comment: Да, я видел эти решения, но возвращается чистый лист и текст скрипта т.е. он не выполняется на непосредственно странице где была отправлена форма.

Comment: Ну так скрипт вы видели как передавался в примере? Целиком, со всеми HTML тегами (`<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello world!');</script>`), а вы передаете просто `OnSuccess();`, Я конечно не занимался таким извратом, это чисто догадки, но может в этом проблема?

Comment: Вот именно этот текс весь и возвращается на чистой странице. А почему изврат? Как сделать по-другому?

Comment: Понимаете в чем дело... Нормальные приложения пишут с использованием подходов, по типу MVC, или MVVM вон в WPF, где все делится на слабо связанные между друг другом слои, где каждый слой отвечает за свое, и не оперирует данными другого. Вот есть слой модели, контроллера, и UI (view), теперь вопрос, к чему относится JS скрипт `OnSuccess();`, к данным, контроллеру, или ui? Я думаю тут очевидно, что это UI элемент, которому место в View слое. Ну а вы вдруг берете, и вызываете его в контроллере... Как быть? Самое банальное, сделать `bool` свойство, и в UI проверять, если `true`, вызывать скрипт.